# Trouble using MySQLi to update and insert to MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli, syntax, insert, sql-update

I believe I have an error in my syntax, but I'm not sure where. I've looked [here for how to insert data](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp), and [here for how to update data](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)....

This is the snippet which updates/inserts the data (PHP)...

```
if ($is_edit === true) {
          $update_query = "UPDATE `$blog_table` SET `title`=$title_value, `content`=$content_value WHERE $identifier";
          $connection->query($update_query);
          header('Location: .');
        } elseif ($is_edit === false) {
          $current_date = date('Y-m-d');
          $add_entry_query = "INSERT INTO $blog_table (date, title, content, comments) VALUES ($current_date, $title_value, $content_value, '')";
          $connection->query($add_entry_query);
          header('Location: .');
        }
```

I know the actual logic is functioning correctly, because I get the page is redirected when the logic is correct.

As far as I can tell, I have copied the syntax exactly, but I'm not getting any data added.

I know for a fact that `$blog_table` and the assorted value variables are correct because I've echoed them to see if they were valid. I also use the exact same `$blog_table` to view data on the same page with the same connection which works flawlessly.

What is the problem with my syntax?

Comment: Add a print statement before the ->query to see what exactly is being sent to your db.

Comment: You're missing quotes around the string values in the queries.

Comment: It would be better to use prepared statements, then you wouldn't have to worry about that.

Comment: You also MISSED the part of the tutorial that actually checks that a `->query()`  suceeded and if not PRINTS THE ERROR which would have allowed you to solve this all on your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you didn't escape strings like this: $title_value="'something'";
change your query to

```
if ($is_edit === true) {
          $update_query = "UPDATE `$blog_table` SET `title`='$title_value', `content`='$content_value' WHERE $identifier";
          $connection->query($update_query);
          header('Location: .');
        } elseif ($is_edit === false) {
          $current_date = date('Y-m-d');
          $add_entry_query = "INSERT INTO $blog_table (date, title, content, comments) VALUES ('$current_date', '$title_value', '$content_value', '')";
          $connection->query($add_entry_query);
          header('Location: .');
        }
```

also make sure your strings are safe,
use function addslashes before using variables in sql

```
$str = addslashes($str);
```

Comment: That was all I needed. I was unaware that I needed to quote the variables. I assumed that the only reason it was like that on the statements was to create a string, which my variables already were.